# How do I write a batch file that moves files to directories where part of the filename matches the folder destination?

Tags: batch-file, directory, match, move

I have lots of files that need to go in specific folders. All the filenames have a certain pattern to them and all the folders that need to hold them. 
How can I write a batch file with the following rule?

1. c:\s1_d1111_c1_p1.mpz needs to move to folder c:\SNC1111
2. c:\s1_d2222_c1_p1.mpz needs to move to folder c:\SNC2222

The filenames always have 4 digits that correspond to the folder. The number after s and c are always 1, and p can have any whole number after it.

This is for Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell
This sample move the files startin in jdk to a child folder jdk

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfile = $files[$i].Name
    if ($outfile.StartsWith("jdk")){
        mkdir -Path "jdk" -Force
        move  $files[$i].FullName "jdk"
    }
}
```

Modify to match your condition and paste the code in a Powershell window

Answer (score 0):

```
 @echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "source=c:\"
    set "targetBase=c:\SNC"

    for /d %%f in ("%source%\"
    ) do for %%a in ("%%~ffs1_d????_c1_p*.mpz"
    ) do for /f "tokens=2 delims=_d" %%b in ("%%~na"
    ) do echo move /y "%%~fa" "%targetBase%%%b\%%~nxa"

    endlocal
```

- `for %%f` used to ensure source path will always have an ending backslash
- `for %%a` used to enumerate the files to process from source
- `for %%b` used to split the name in parts and do the move

`move` command is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove `echo`